# Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

how to post from html form in
[image]
django rest framework api i am getting error as Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str.

Comment: please share the code. image isn't enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are passing the PK value.  It will likely need to be an integer and not a string value.

Also, as Hemal noted, it's best that you share your code: views.py, any serializer, and possibly even your models.py.